# Vertical UITableView Section Header

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement a UITableView with vertical header something like the following image

as you can see the Test word will be the section header , can I create a custom header like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, You cant do this in UITableview controller. You can use custom horizantal table view for https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable

Comment: I need it vertical , will this do that

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible...you may use a `UIScrollView` with multiple tableviews if you know the no of header in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take use `UILabel`, add **Title** to it, [Rotate it to 90 Degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291991/1603072) and then place it to the left of `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display complex UI Components the best way to do this is a `UICollectionView`. If you need to Support iOS 5 you can use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). `UICollectionView` have a very common API to `UITableView`.

With `UICollectionView` you can create very complex User Interfaces like the one you need. And the best about this is that you can completely cutting lines between Model / View / Controller.

A good start is to watch the Videos from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) with `UICollectionView` as the topic. They explain very good how to build complex CollectionViews and why they are better to create horizontal tables like you want to build.